# Error (2322): Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined' when assigning to a Partial type

Tags: typescript

I stumbled upon the TypeScript error `Error (2322): Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'` when trying to assign to a `Partial<Person>` type, using the keys of the original `keyof Person` type stored as string, as following. I also figured some working solutions below, but I wonder what would be the more proper way of handling such specific case?

TypeScript [playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwFBSlQEMBbCALikWHgEtUBzAGnyoFd5izLq7GWCRACZD4ERIh416zVkQYVCbEgCMEAqsjLAAFjICiAG0SLeMjSm17GRkwEYpfWQUsRdB4xABMj86wD0-gB0IbgAvri4oJCwCCioAGLI8CQAkqhgbMCYOKy0QpQA1hAgyABmsUhoGgBuRIZsptL84QDckQDGaNRQkFWJyWkZWXZQlHD9SSnpmdlYeAT5lADkXBDLtfWNKwBSyDqoy%20Gd3dl98VNDs15jlReDM1k5C1BLUMuIHGsbrHUNissACLIdYsCK4QKYAB8UHSUHciCgHSIJlewA%20UDK9GgwGQUDYqIABgBtc5oS6PYB2IL5AC6hKgKMZUGKIBCQVwXVQPTJqEpADUtuJbjAiPBgLR6gAeCbxGHzVikuLkh7DKk0oS0yi8ilq6l-RoWLRuawMWwAgAeIAAXj9wZCMDCAEIAVQAKuzYegEUiUdBaOjEahkNksagIJ6ABQAQV68GQKkMEBIAH4AJQQ-xQfTwePwShu8DQD7NBjLV5BkOMiS0BjERM4vHRYtsVBCCBhiBCcuRrwAZi8XgzvIFQsQSsmquuGtpOR1U6yXiCBog7RHasF-3H8%20maqXdLnyoGu%20nK6gKZT72W7Uz2dzyQLRfeZkYUAAPvi2x3sd2K4QqyiiC1vWSbwk2T7LK27adr%20vYDkOuDrrMm6NNuR66tOB5YDuVyLsuQrVlQpbvp%200E-jekI5nmj4xCWTjlrQlbZIBwFEA2YHwhBUHfuGsH9oOw5HqOW4TvcJ54fkhGsuUdxoLO2HoQuwBLiuFFZlRD5QIWtEvmWf7BsxNZ1mxoG4pxtHcTBPb8QhSFZCh4iiSq4nKRqUklDJoripKhgykeULyb0ikuSpQpqVpeiIgA7skhSIEwUAqE8ZQQBAxhQFF8aMIhQkbmOTnHrhrlYUFk4hfh-yEUQqAgOFbqRRlsXxYlTwBhiHRJmKhggFAJCMZ1QgyIRqQZdVwBds%20XykOsrzeg1yImAlSXZCNYj1N1hCpUIUCEtJFSymgDJmQS-rZAo4Z0MihgbfQ8I6NAhjIMgYA5f0wmoQVGESdtTKrNNyyBThlKhf87RAA).

So basically the following works on the new object `[personFormInput1.id]: personFormInput1.value;` or `personInputValues = {...personInputValues, [personFormInput2.id]: personFormInput2.value};`, but not on the existing object `personInputValues[personFormInput2.id] = personFormInput2.value;`. I struggle to understand why.

```js
type Person = {
  name: string,
  surname: string,
  address: string,
  age: number,
  somethingElse: string,
  somethingElse1: string,
  somethingElse2: string,
  //...
}

type PersonFormInput = {
  id: keyof Person,
  value: string,
};

const personFormInput1 : PersonFormInput = {
  id: 'name',
  value: 'John'
}

const personFormInput2 : PersonFormInput = {
  id: 'surname',
  value: 'Doe',
}

// => In this case it's fine to use `[personFormInput1.id]` as a key...
const personInputValues : Partial<Person> = {
  [personFormInput1.id]: personFormInput1.value,
  somethingElse: 'xyz',
}

// => BUT... In this case it's not fine... (A problem?)
// Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined' (2322)
personInputValues[personFormInput2.id] = personFormInput2.value;
personInputValues[personFormInput2.id] = personFormInput2.value ?? '';

// Error: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'undefined' (2322)
personInputValues[personFormInput2.id] = personFormInput2.value as string | undefined;

// Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined' (2322)
personInputValues[personFormInput2.id as keyof Person] = personFormInput2.value;

// Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined' (2322)
personInputValues[personFormInput2.id as keyof Partial<Person>] = personFormInput2.value;

// This works, but feels wrong
personInputValues[personFormInput2.id] = personFormInput2.value as any;

// This works, but it's clearly misleading as I wanted 'surname' in this case, but I really need `keyof Person` to use it generically in the loop
personInputValues[personFormInput2.id as 'name'] = personFormInput2.value;
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wXrRJm) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame. Surely this is a working solution and definitely post it! Thanks a lot! Some explanation would be cool too! I only wonder isn't there a simpler solution? Maybe stupid question, I am new to TypeScript but long in JS. I will accept this answer if there is no simpler solution soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of the `age: number`. If you change its type to `string` the errors will go away. Since your `PersonFormInput` has an `id` of `keyof Person` it also includes `id` which expects `number`, however your value is always `string` and therefore you face the issue with `never` because compiler finds an intersection of values when you do `person[personFormInput.id]` which `string & number` and it is equivalent to `never`.

The proper solution would be to convert `PersonFormInput` to a union type where the member of union is specific key of the `Person` and the value has the type of that specific property. This can be achieved using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
// type PersonFormInput = {
//     id: "name";
//     value: string;
// } | {
//     id: "surname";
//     value: string;
// } | {
//     id: "address";
//     value: string;
// } | {
//     id: "age";
//     value: number;
// } | {
//     id: "somethingElse";
//     value: string;
// } | {
//     id: "somethingElse1";
//     value: string;
// } | {
//     ...;
// }
type PersonFormInput = {
  [K in keyof Person]: { id: K; value: Person[K] };
}[keyof Person];
```

Now you can assign values for properties without errors as you expected:

```
const personFormInput1: PersonFormInput = {
  id: 'name',
  value: 'John',
};

const personFormInput2: PersonFormInput = {
  id: 'surname',
  value: 'Doe',
};

const personInputValues: Partial<Person> = {
  [personFormInput1.id]: personFormInput1.value,
  somethingElse: 'xyz',
};

personInputValues[personFormInput2.id] = personFormInput2.value ?? '';
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/wXrRJm)

Comment: Oh wow, thanks a lot. It's much better explanation than `type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'`, I wonder why the error message does not say about `string | number`. The `number` is not mentioned at all...

Comment: For me it actually says: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.`

Comment: In the link from my first post? For me all 5 reported errors say `'undefined'`. How is this possible?

Comment: Try to click `Ts Config` in the playground and turn off the `strictNullChecks` options

Comment: yes that does it, thanks! Is it good to keep this option off? It seems to only confuse me

Comment: As you wish, when it's off, typescript doesn't distinct `null` from `undefined`. [Reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks)